# How to use swc to make ast restore be code segment

Tags: javascript, swc-compiler

My code segment is this:

```
<>
    <Divider orientation="left">{resultLinkTitle}</Divider>
    <Intension />
    <Form form={form} name="auditForm" ref={auditFormRef}>
      <Form.Item label="files">
        <Button type="link" onClick={() => handleDownLoadFile(aduitInfo?.fileUrl)}>
          download
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  </>
```

then I use `swc.parse` to get ast. But I cannot get the original code with `swc.printSync`. It returns an error `unknown variant 'JSXElement', expected 'Module' or 'Script'`.
How can I solve this?

How do I get the original code with swc.

Answer (score 0):

I know what hapend. It's not a data struct like `swc.Program`. I should create it like this:

```
{
  type: 'Module',
  span: { start: 0, end: 100, ctxt:0 },
  body: [...]
}
```